# Increasing impulse on collision in box2d

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, collision-detection, physics

I'm creating box2d game and trouble is as follows:
Two fighters located on arena, top view. Fighters has weapons like sword in theis hands. I want to fighter bounces in hit direction when damaged by opponent, but fighters has same physical characteristics and applied impulse is not sufficient to bounce fighter considerably.
How can I increase applied by box2d impulse in same (correct) direction? I overrided PostSolve method, but I don't understand how to affect to b2ContactImpulse passed to method. I think I just need increase value of that impulse, but I dont know how. Could someone explain me how to do it? Thanx!